# Override height of a single MenuItem in a NavigationView

Tags: android, android-layout, navigationview, android-navigationview

I'd like to increase the height of a **single** `MenuItem` inside a `NavigationView`.

I am trying to put a Google `MapFragment` inside the item's [`actionLayout`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource), as shown below, but I want the height of the map to be larger.

Any ideas?

#### Note:

- I want to utilise the standard menu layout of the NavigationView (I'd prefer not to have to implement a whole custom menu layout as using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31716815/1513557)).
- I don't want to change the height of **all** items like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44644656/1513557), only the map item.

[image: Screenshot showing map inside NavigationView MenuItem]

#### `activity_main_drawer.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    ...

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_map"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/nav_map"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/fragment_map" />

    ...

</menu>
```

#### `fragment_map.xml`

Adjusting `android:layout_height` here has no effect.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/nav_map_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    map:mapType="normal"
    map:liteMode="true"/>
```

#### In `Activity.onCreate(...)` in `MainActivity.kt`

Setting the height on the action view has no effect here.

```
val mapItem = nav.menu.findItem(R.id.nav_map)

// Has no effect: trying to set height to 128dp
mapItem.actionView.layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 128)

// Hack: hide title
mapItem.title = null

val mapView = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_map_fragment) as SupportMapFragment
mapView.getMapAsync { map ->
    ...
}
```

Comment: Did you find the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this problem by creating an extension function that will do two things:

1. Remove the title of the `MenuItem` (i.e. `title = null`)
2. Attach a state change listener to the `MenuItem`

The state change listener has the purpose of, when the item is attached to the window, finding the parent of the action view and setting it's height to `WRAP_CONTENT` (and storing the original height). When the view is detached, it restores the original height. This is because it seems like the views are actually recycled between different items as you scroll... so you'd otherwise find that gradually all of the items in the menu are affected, not just your target item.

The extension function is implemented below:

```
fun MenuItem.fillActionView() {
    // Hide the title text
    title = null

    // Fill the action view
    val thisView = actionView
    thisView.addOnAttachStateChangeListener(object: View.OnAttachStateChangeListener {
        private var originalHeight: Int? = null

        override fun onViewAttachedToWindow(view: View?) {
            if (view === thisView) {
                val v = view?.parent?.parent as? View
                if (v != null) {
                    v.layoutParams = v.layoutParams
                            .apply {
                                originalHeight = height
                                height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                            }
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onViewDetachedFromWindow(view: View?) {
            val h = originalHeight
            val v = view?.parent?.parent as? View
            if ((h != null) && (v != null)) {
                v.layoutParams = v.layoutParams
                        .apply {
                            height = h
                            originalHeight = null
                        }
            }
        }
    })

}
```

You can use it in your activity's `onCreate()` like so:

```
val mapItem = nav.menu.findItem(R.id.nav_map) // Find your menu item which has the action view set
mapItem.fillActionView()
```

**Java code:**

```
View.OnAttachStateChangeListener menuItemActionViewStateListener = new View.OnAttachStateChangeListener() {
    int originalHeight = 0;

    @Override
    public void onViewAttachedToWindow(View v) {
        View parent = (View) v.getParent();
        if (parent != null)
            parent = (View)parent.getParent();

        if (parent != null) {
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams p = parent.getLayoutParams();
            originalHeight = p.height;
            p.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            parent.requestLayout();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(View v) {
        if (originalHeight != 0) {
            View parent = (View) v.getParent();
            if (parent != null)
                parent = (View)parent.getParent();

            if (parent != null) {
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams p = parent.getLayoutParams();
                p.height = originalHeight;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

And just use it like here:

```
final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_menu_item, null);
v.addOnAttachStateChangeListener(menuItemActionViewStateListener);

menuItem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
menuItem.setActionView(v);
menuItem.setIcon(null);
menuItem.setTitle(null);
```

I hope this is helpful to others.

Comment: Thanks, your fix did the job for me also. I am adding the Java code to the answer.